# Display alert based on characters in placeholder in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

What I'm trying to achieve:

1) user hovers over placeholder

2) if user typed more than 3 characters in placeholder and mouse leaves of placeholder > display #alert

3) if user removes characters in placeholder to less than 3 > hide alert

```js
jQuery('#mydiv').after('<span id="alert">alert</span>');
jQuery('#myinput').mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery('#alert').toggle(this.value !== '');
});
```

```css
#alert {
    display: block;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv">
    <input id="myinput" placeholder="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the length of the input, then display the alert

on `input` if length < 3, hide alert.

```js
$('#mydiv').after('<span id="alert">alert</span>');

$('#myinput').mouseleave(function() {
    if(this.value.length >= 3) $('#alert').show()
});

$('#myinput').on('input', function(){
  if(this.value.length < 3) $('#alert').hide();
})
```

```css
#alert {
    display: block;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv">
    <input id="myinput" placeholder="">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, hovewer alert doesn't dissapear when characters are removed. Also can we do it all on focus

Comment: @benua glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myinput').on('input', function() {
    if (this.value.length < 3) {
        $('#alert').hide();
    } else {
        $('#alert').show();
    }
})
```

```css
#alert {
    display: none;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv">
    <label>Value: </label>
    <input id="myinput" placeholder="Enter Value">
    <span id="alert">Value must be less than three</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!